# how to rewrite django test case to avoid unpredictable occasional failures

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have a test case that's written **exactly** like this

```
def test_material_search_name(self):
    """
    Tests for `LIKE` condition in searches.
    For both name and serial number.
    """
    material_one = MaterialFactory(name="Eraenys Velinarys", serial_number="SB2341")
    material_two = MaterialFactory(name="Nelaerla Velnaris", serial_number="TB7892")

    response = self.client.get(reverse('material-search'), {'q': 'vel'})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.assertEqual(response.data['count'], 2)
    self.assertEqual(response.data['results'][0]['name'], material_one.name)
    self.assertEqual(response.data['results'][1]['name'], material_two.name)
```

My error message is :

```
line 97, in test_material_search_name
    self.assertEqual(response.data['results'][0]['name'], material_one.name)
AssertionError: 'Nelaerla Velnaris' != 'Eraenys Velinarys'
- Nelaerla Velnaris
+ Eraenys Velinarys
```

Then when i re-run without changing any code, it becomes successful.

This error happens occasionally not always.

I was wondering if there's a better way to achieve the objectives of the test case without having that weird failure once in a while.

The frequency this error occurs is around 1 every 50 times I run the test.

The typical test command I use :

```
python manage.py test app_name.tests --keepdb
```

Comment: You could order the results you get back by name before doing the `assertEqual`s _or_ you could collect all the names out of the results first and then for each name do `self.assertIn(name, names)` _or_ you could order the results the back end returns.

Comment: I picked ur second suggestion which works better. U mind writing as an answer? I will green tick it as soon as SO allows it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

- Order the results you get back by name before doing the `assertEqual`s
- Collect all the names out of the results first and then for each name do `self.assertIn(name, names)`
- Order the results the back end returns